# How to integrate saml to your springboot application with jumpcloud as the idp

Tags: spring-boot, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml, idp

We would like to add one of our internal apps to jumpcloud (we use jumpcloud as our exisiting IDP to login to different services like MS-Office). now to add the internal app to it I firstly am doing a proof-of-concept with a dummy springboot application. I added the following this to spring boot app.

application.properties:

```
`spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.jumpcloud.assertingparty.metadata-uri=https://sso.jumpcloud.com/saml2/metadata/64b663a87f16d2qwertyuky234`
```

this url is the metdata url given by jumpcloud to
Controller:

```
`@RestController("/saml")
@Slf4j
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/something")
    public String home(@AuthenticationPrincipal Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("name", principal.getName());
        model.addAttribute("emailAddress", principal.getFirstAttribute("email"));
        model.addAttribute("userAttributes", principal.getAttributes());
        log.info(model.toString());
        return "home";
 }`
```

pom.xml:

```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-saml-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>`
```

Main SpringbootApplication

`package com.saml.ssoDemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ssoDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OktaSsoApplication.class, args);
    }

}`
```

JUMPCLOUD CONFIGURATIONS:
I logged in from my admin account>selected SSO>selected custom SAML app>Added the following settings>

[SP and IDP config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVQKK.png)
[ACS URL(the url which it should redirect me to as soon as it authenticates me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2deo0.png)

AND HERE IS THE IDP url jumpcloud generated:
[IDP URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUIig.png)

However when i load up the app it and put in the credentials it redirects me in a loop to the IDP url.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rEly.png)